# Event log error player.SoundLocation() failed

Tags: event-log, norton-antivirus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display messages from a remote computer](https://superuser.com/questions/308049/the-local-computer-may-not-have-the-necessary-registry-information-or-message-dll)

We have a client machine 'secon' (XP-Pro, SP3)  and server machine 'servlet'. When  upgraded Norton AV from 11.4 to RU6 one of our application named 'LeaftradeSoundLauncher' doesnot start. When i checked 'secon' application syslogs(application) which they  i found

> The description for Event ID ( 0 ) in
>   Source ( Sound Alerts ) cannot be
>   found. The local computer may not have
>   the necessary registry information or
>   message DLL files to display messages
>   from a remote computer. You may be
>   able to use the /AUXSOURCE= flag to
>   retrieve this description; see Help
>   and Support for details. The following
>   information is part of the event:
>   SoundAlerts::player.SoundLocation()
>   failed.  Sound file
>   C:\WINDOWS\Media\SSRoam.wav was not
>   found!** Downside that ican see one
>   more entry source'msiinstaller'
>   **Product: Sound Alerts (SA) -- Removal completed successfully.

Any body knows what will be the reason here, upgrading antivirus will affect our product?